# React Route Firebase Auth Redirect after login

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I am trying to redirect the user to UserProfile after login.
I can login the user successfully but once logged in I cannot figure out why it doesn't redirect me to the UserProfile page.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anybody have a look at this?

**App.js**

```
// ...
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) { this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })} 
      else { this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })}
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={Landing} exact />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route path='/user-profile' render={() => (
            this.state.isLoggedIn ? <UserProfile /> : <Redirect to='/login' />
          )} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```
// ...
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Login extends Component {
    this.state = {
        // ...
    };

    _handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(() => {
                // ...
                this.props.history.push('/recipe-form')
            }).catch((error) => {
                // ... 
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => this._handleSubmit(e)}>
                <Input //...Email />
                <Input //...Password />
                <Button text='Login' type='submit' />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Comment: The state has changed but not the route, you could try redirecting to `/user-profile` upon successful login.

Comment: @FrancescMontserrat - isn't that what I am doing with 
`<Route path='/user-profile' render={() => (
      this.state.isLoggedIn ? <UserProfile /> : <Redirect to='/login' />
)}/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checker you are putting on

`<Route path='/user-profile' render={() => ( this.state.isLoggedIn ? <UserProfile /> : <Redirect to='/login' /> )}/>`

here says that if user currently on `user-profile` path and he is not logged in, he should suppose to be re directed, but it is says nothing on user that currently in `login` path.

You can add same (but opposite) logic to `Route` login decleration -

`<Route path='/login' render={() => ( !this.state.isLoggedIn ? <Login /> : <Redirect to='/user-profile' /> )}/>`

or add `Redirect` at `Login` component itself after successful login attempt